# How to avoid duplicates in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is my coding:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive).Title("Active Status").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='active' ${ IsActive == true ? checked='checked' : ''} enabled value='#= IsActive#' />");
```

Event:

```
.Events(events => events.RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd").Change("index"))
.Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Create"))
.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Read"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Update"))
```

Function to check duplicate values:

```
function index(dataItem) {

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridData = grid._data;
    console.log("gridData>>", gridData);
    console.log("dataItem>>", dataItem);

    if (grid.dataItem(grid.select()) != null || grid.dataItem(grid.select()) != undefined) {
        selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        console.log("selectedItem>>", selectedItem.ProviderTypeName);

        for (item in gridData) {
            console.log("grid[item].ProviderTypeName>>", gridData[item].ProviderTypeName);
            console.log("selectedItem", selectedItem.ProviderTypeName);
            if (gridData[item].ProviderTypeName == selectedItem.ProviderTypeName && gridData[item].Id != selectedItem.Id) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                grid.bind("dataBinding", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
                grid.unbind("dataBinding");
                grid.refresh();
                alert("Duplicates not allowed");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

These are my coding . I want to prevent entering of duplicate values in the kendo grid. Can anyone let me what I am doing is correct or Should I do something else. I want to stop duplicated values both in Create and Update even in my kendo grid.

Answer (score 0):

The environment of the question should be further detailed by adding the code that is the grid's model (the entity framework class), and the tables design (the CREATE TABLE statement).

Prevention of duplicates is most often implemented as a server side feature in the form of table constraints in the data base.  It looks like you want to prevent a duplicate `Name` from being entered.

Depending on how the application was built (code first / data first) you might have

Model class field with unique annotation

```
[Index("Unique_Name", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

or table constraint

```
[name] VARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [unique_name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([name] ASC)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in client side?How do we show the user that he has entered duplicate value. I mean the message?

Comment: A little searching around the Telerik forums can give you additional insights.  https://www.telerik.com/forums/checking-the-kendo-grid-for-duplicate-values

Comment: I checked the same link before. The alert message appears but the save event occurs. Thats the problem.

Comment: Also e.model.UserName throws an error that it could not be found

Comment: What is the motivation client side checking ?  If the checks are not done server side a theoretical black hat actor could potentially create a duplicate (using methods that bypass the grid and your ui page).

Comment: Thank you for making me understand. Can you tell me some other ways In which I could do this on server side. Just for a knowledge. Thanks